# How in Silverlight correctly notify to change one custom property from another property binding to different controls?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have this MainPage.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" Height="246" Width="562">

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="552" ShowGridLines="True" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="275" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="113"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                <RowDefinition Height="45" />
                <RowDefinition Height="45" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Slider x:Name="sliderLoanAmount" Value="{Binding LoanAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="35" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10000" Minimum="0" Maximum="700000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="265" Margin="0" TabIndex="1" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="textLoanAmount" Text="{Binding LoanAmount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="14" FontStretch="Normal" TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0" TabIndex="2" />

        <Slider x:Name="sliderDownPaymentPercent" Value="{Binding DownPaymentPercent, Mode=TwoWay}" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="265" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="3" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="textDownPaymentAmount" Text="{Binding DownPaymentAmount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="14" FontStretch="Normal" TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0" TabIndex="3" />

        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Also I have custom LoanData class with properties binding to slider and textbox controls:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    private LoanData Loan
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loan = new LoanData { LoanAmount = 700000, DownPaymentPercent = 20, DownPaymentAmount = 140000};
        this.DataContext = this.Loan;
    }
}

public class LoanData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private long _LoanAmount;
    public long LoanAmount
    {
        get { return _LoanAmount; }
        set
        {
            if (_LoanAmount != value)
            {
                _LoanAmount = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LoanAmount");
            }
        }
    }

    private long _DownPaymentPercent;
    public long DownPaymentPercent
    {
        get { return _DownPaymentPercent; }
        set
        {
            if (_DownPaymentPercent != value)
            {
                _DownPaymentPercent = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentPercent");

                DownPaymentAmount = DownPaymentAmount;
                //NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");
            }
            else
            {
                if (LoanAmount != 0)
                {
                    _DownPaymentPercent = (DownPaymentAmount / LoanAmount) * 100;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentPercent");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private long _DownPaymentAmount;
    public long DownPaymentAmount
    {
        get { return _DownPaymentAmount; }
        set
        {
            if (_DownPaymentAmount != value)
            {
                _DownPaymentAmount = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");

                DownPaymentPercent = DownPaymentPercent;
                //NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentPercent");
            }
            else
            {
                _DownPaymentAmount = (DownPaymentPercent * LoanAmount) / 100;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Controls sliderLoanAmount and textLoanAmount binding to LoanAmount property. Changing slider position leads to changing text value and vise versa.

But I need more complex logic for next two controls.
When I reposition sliderDownPaymentPercent control textDownPaymentAmount value must be DownPaymentAmount = (DownPaymentPercent * LoanAmount) / 100.
When I changed value in textDownPaymentAmount control sliderDownPaymentPercent must reposition to value DownPaymentPercent = (DownPaymentAmount / LoanAmount) * 100.

When I reposition sliderDownPaymentPercent execute this code:

```
if (_DownPaymentPercent != value)
{
    _DownPaymentPercent = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentPercent");

    DownPaymentAmount = DownPaymentAmount;
    //NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");
}
```

I want to tell textDownPaymentAmount to change its value by calling

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");
```

but its not work and only solution I find:

```
 DownPaymentAmount = DownPaymentAmount;
```

This lead to exxecute this code:

```
else
{
    _DownPaymentAmount = (DownPaymentPercent * LoanAmount) / 100;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");
}
```

When I typing in textDownPaymentAmount execute code:

```
if (_DownPaymentAmount != value)
{
    _DownPaymentAmount = value;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");

    DownPaymentPercent = DownPaymentPercent;
    //NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentPercent");
}
```

As you can see I have to call again

```
DownPaymentPercent = DownPaymentPercent;
```

instead

```
 //NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentPercent");
```

So my question is how correctly notify to change one property from another property without 
using this:

```
DownPaymentPercent = DownPaymentPercent;
```

OR

```
DownPaymentAmount = DownPaymentAmount;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using type of long for your properties and slider values need to be of type double.

Try this:

```
    <Slider x:Name="sliderLoanAmount" Value="{Binding LoanAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="35" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10000" Minimum="0" Maximum="700000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="265" Margin="0" TabIndex="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="textLoanAmount" Text="{Binding LoanAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="14" FontStretch="Normal" TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0" TabIndex="2" />

    <Slider x:Name="sliderDownPaymentPercent" Value="{Binding DownPaymentPercent, Mode=TwoWay}" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="265" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="3" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="textDownPaymentAmount" Text="{Binding DownPaymentAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="14" FontStretch="Normal" TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="0" TabIndex="3" />

public class LoanData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private double _LoanAmount;
    public double LoanAmount
    {
        get { return _LoanAmount; }
        set
        {
            if (_LoanAmount != value)
            {
                _LoanAmount = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LoanAmount");
                DownPaymentAmount = (DownPaymentPercent / 100) * LoanAmount;
            }
        }
    }

    private double _DownPaymentPercent;
    public double DownPaymentPercent
    {
        get { return _DownPaymentPercent; }
        set
        {
            if (_DownPaymentPercent != value)
            {
                _DownPaymentPercent = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentPercent");
                DownPaymentAmount = (DownPaymentPercent / 100) * LoanAmount;
            }
        }
    }

    private double _DownPaymentAmount;
    public double DownPaymentAmount
    {
        get { return _DownPaymentAmount; }
        set
        {
            if (_DownPaymentAmount != value)
            {
                _DownPaymentAmount = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");
                DownPaymentPercent = (DownPaymentAmount / LoanAmount) * 100;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob ! Actually I have custom derived slider which can handle lond value insted of double. My question is how from one property notify another property without code like this DownPaymentAmount = DownPaymentAmount.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would need to notify another property has changed when that other properties value has not changed?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the problem here:
In both your setters for DownPaymentPercent and DownPaymentAmount you do a recalculation of the backing field _DownPaymentPercent resp. _DownPaymentAmount whenever the "new" value is the same as the "old" value.
see:

```
if (_DownPaymentAmount != value)
{
   /*snip*/
}
else
{
    _DownPaymentAmount = (DownPaymentPercent * LoanAmount) / 100;
    NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");
}
```

That means your statement `DownPaymentPercent = DownPaymentPercent;` actually changes the value of DownPaymentPercent (and triggers NotifyPropertyChanged).
So your (now commented-out) call of NotifyPropertyChanged actually worked, but alas! the value of the backing field was still the old value (no recalculation has been done, the binding was actually updated but you saw no change in your UI because your DataContext supplied the same value that was already displayed).
To fix this you must do a recalculation of the other dependent values everytime one of your setters is called with a new value:

```
//setter for DownPaymentAmount...
set
{
    if (_DownPaymentAmount != value)
    {
        _DownPaymentAmount = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");

        //recalculate dependent property backing field
        if (LoanAmount != 0)
        {
            _DownPaymentPercent = (DownPaymentAmount / LoanAmount) * 100;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentPercent");
        }
    }
}

//...and setter for DownPaymentPercent
set
{
    if (_DownPaymentPercent != value)
    {
        _DownPaymentPercent = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentPercent");

        //recalculate dependent property backing field
        _DownPaymentAmount = (DownPaymentPercent * LoanAmount) / 100;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount");
    }
}
```

[Edit] Your statement `_DownPaymentPercent = (DownPaymentAmount / LoanAmount) * 100;` will most likely result in _DownPaymentPercent beeing 0 due to integer arithmetic.
`DownPaymentAmount / LoanAmount` results in 0 and multiplying 0 with 100 is still 0.

Comment: You will notice in my suggested solution I did the same thing, moved the calc to inside the if statement. In the setter for _DownPaymentPercent, NotifyPropertyChanged("DownPaymentAmount") is not necessary as that should occur in the _DownPaymentAmount setter if the value actually changed.

Comment: My solution is slightly different: I'm not calling the setter but instead manipulating the backing field directly (therefore I have to call NotifyPropertyChanged explicitly, and I dare say it is not unnecessary because the value actually did change). Your solution runs the risc of triggering a cyclic update of the two dependent values due to rounding errors (I'm sure it will terminate though).

Comment: Gotcha.  The pattern I follow is update the public variable and let the setter handle the NotifyPropertyChanged.  My solution should not introduce a cyclic update with the != value check.